# Angular, jQuery and Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

I am trying to create a chrome extension that modifies the content a specific website. Since I do not have access to the src code of the website i have to change it through javascript

I want the new content to be dynamic and updates through angular (the original website does not use angular).

i am injecting a tag with `ng-app` and `ng-controller` and create an angular app and controller in js.

However the page does not understand the angular html directives and render it verbatim.

What am i doing wrong?

from the tutorial code :
i am injecting this to the html (using js code that's injected by chrome extension, on page load):

```
<div ng-app="phonecatApp" ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

and this to the js (injected through extension, on page load):

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

which is run after page load

Answer (score 1):

it might be a silly question, but did you also inject the angular.js library in the page before injecting your angular code?

Answer (score 0):

I did not bootstrap.
Apparently the ng directives are compiled on `DOMContentLoaded` which happened way before i injected anything. So I need to initialize angular myself

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['phonecatApp']);
});
```